# Specify explicitly the model data type MVC/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Since `@Html.EditorFor()` is building an input field according to the model data type. I'd like to use this method and generate a textbox for a model variable of the DATETIME type, instead of a calendar. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Either `TextBoxFor` or `[DataType(DataType.Text)]`, AFAIK. The real question is why you want to edit a DateTime as if it were text.

Comment: @CodeCaster [DataType(DataType.Text)] doesn't work and TextBoxFor i know it's gonna generate a textbox but the whole point was can you use FormEditorFor and get a textbox for DateTime var.

Comment: @CodeCaster I need to parse it to sql in DateTime format.

Comment: What is `FormEditorFor()`? That's not part of MVC (or did you mean `EditorFor()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, that's what i meant, apologize for any confusion.

Comment: @NaughtyNinja, The whole purpose of using `EditorFor()` is to generate the control based on the property type (in the case of `DateTime` it generates `type="datetime"`) so if you only want a text box, use the method that creates an `<input type="text" />` (`TextBoxFor()`) - its far better performance anyway. Use the right tools for the job, don't try to adapt a screwdriver to make it a hammer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own helper to display and manage date.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DatePickerFor<TModel, TProperty>
(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    string datePickerName = 
          ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    string datePickerFullName = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.
                   TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName
                   (datePickerName);
    string datePickerID = TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId
                          (datePickerFullName);

    ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression
                             (expression, helper.ViewData);
    DateTime datePickerValue = (metadata.Model == null ? 
                             DateTime.Now : DateTime.Parse(
                             metadata.Model.ToString()));

    TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("input");
    tag.Attributes.Add("name", datePickerFullName);
    tag.Attributes.Add("id", datePickerID);
    tag.Attributes.Add("type", "date");
    tag.Attributes.Add("value", datePickerValue.
                                ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    IDictionary<string, object> validationAttributes = helper.
    GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes
    (datePickerFullName, metadata);

    foreach (string key in validationAttributes.Keys)
    {
        tag.Attributes.Add(key, validationAttributes[key].ToString());
    }

    MvcHtmlString html=new MvcHtmlString(
               tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    return html;
}
```

to prepare the use of the helper

```
public class EmployeeMetadata
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMetadata))]
public partial class Employee
{
}

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
        return View(db.Employees.First());
    }
```

and you can use your helper

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
@using(Html.BeginForm("ProcessForm","Home",FormMethod.Post))
    {        
        @Html.DatePicker("birthdateUnbound")
        @Html.DatePickerFor(m=>m.BirthDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.BirthDate)
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

To submit your form

```
public ActionResult ProcessForm(Employee obj)
{
    return View("Index",obj);
}
```